# Search for a string in memory and modify the value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory, process

I found the following code in another StackOverflow question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class outIter>
void find_locs(HANDLE process, std::string const &pattern, outIter output) {

    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for ( p = NULL;
        VirtualQueryEx(process, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize ) 
    {
        std::vector<char> buffer;
        std::vector<char>::iterator pos;

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT && 
            (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)) 
        {
            DWORD bytes_read;
            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(process, p, &buffer[0], info.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);
            for ( pos = buffer.begin();
                buffer.end()!=(pos=std::search(pos, buffer.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end()));
                ++pos)
            {
                *output++ = p+(pos-buffer.begin());
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <process ID> <pattern>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int pid;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%i", &pid);

    std::string pattern(argv[2]);

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess( 
        PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
        false,
        pid);

    find_locs(process, pattern, 
        std::ostream_iterator<void *>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

but this is to search for bytes. I want to search for a specific string in memory using which I can read the value associated with it and then modify it if it meets a certain condition. Like, the string MakeAllAppsDefault in explorer.exe's memory stores the value 0x00000000 or 0x00000001 (depending on what's the value of MakeAllAppsDefault in registry) and I would like to change it.

Comment: You can't search for a string in an running process and just assume the associated registry value's magically next to it.  If you want to start doing stuff like this, you'd be best off spending a few months in a debugger learning about realistic memory layout and what programs do with data as they execute.

Comment: @TonyD : I didn't assume, IT IS THERE. But the problem is, the memory address isn't constant (obviously) and if I search for 0 or 1 values then I will get crapload of results, so I was looking for a way to get the value associated with MakeAllAppsDefault from memory.

Comment: If it's was a variable name in Explorer's source code, and survives as a symbol in the executable and memory images (seems unlikely to me), even then you'd want to use a debugging library - e.g. DbgHelp.dll (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679294(v=vs.85).aspx) and look up symbols with it. If it's in the source code because it's being passed as an argument to a get-registry-value function, then it's even less useful... only by tracing the code in a debugger can you see where it gets stored; the address of the string literal parameter's unrelated to the return value.

Comment: Assuming the 0 or 1 follows immediately after the "MakeAllAppsDefault" in memory, this this should find the location just fine. The obvious problem that would be likely to arise would be if it stores that as a Unicode string, in which case you'd have to convert the name to Unicode before searching. Oh -- one other detail: on line 34, `bytes_read` should really be a `SIZE_T` instead of a `DWORD`.